# What does Spring Boot test default configurations warn "Parameter 'systemProperties' is deprecated"?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-test, spring-bean, spring-shell

In a Spring Boot test, when I annotated with @SpringBootTest,
I get warning:

```
Parameter 'systemProperties' is deprecated: Use systemPropertyVariables instead.
```

Why is that and how can I fix it?

This error might be fair if I used the `systemProperties` variable.
For instance like:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, properties = {"key1=value1", "key2=value2"}, systemProperties = {"sysKey1=sysValue1", "sysKey2=sysValue2"})
```

Then I might be able to fix it by something like

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, properties = {"key1=value1", "key2=value2"}, systemPropertyVariables = {"sysKey1=sysValue1", "sysKey2=sysValue2"})
```

Following are my Spring versions used:

```
mvn dependency:tree | grep spring
[INFO] +- org.springframework.shell:spring-shell-starter:jar:3.1.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.shell:spring-shell-autoconfigure:jar:3.1.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:3.1.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.shell:spring-shell-core:jar:3.1.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:jar:3.1.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:6.0.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:6.0.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.shell:spring-shell-standard:jar:3.1.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.shell:spring-shell-standard-commands:jar:3.1.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.shell:spring-shell-table:jar:3.1.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:6.0.13:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:6.0.13:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:6.0.13:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:3.1.5:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:3.1.5:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:3.1.5:compile
[INFO] \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:3.1.5:test
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:3.1.5:test
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:3.1.5:test
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:6.0.13:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:6.0.13:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:6.0.13:test
```

Anything I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with Spring Boot.

The warning you have shared is from Maven Surefire, and it's telling you to use `<systemPropertyVariables>` instead of `<systemProperties>` in your `pom.xml`.

See [Surefire's documentation](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/system-properties.html) for details.

Comment: It goes away when I remove the @SpringBootTest, what does that suggest?

Comment: Without a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), I unfortunately cannot assess that.